# function with function argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I just wondering to find a keyword or a solution so that I can further find and fix my own problem, so basically, I wanted to call a function but from a function argument, like this.

```
var arg = function() {/*do something*/};

function do(arg) {
  arg();
}

do(arg);
```

But I want to put multiple functions on it, but not constant, it sometimes can be 1 function, or sometimes 2 functions or more, is there any solution that I can take? or a keyword to I start searching with? I already searched the internet but I could not find what I want.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, a pipeline might be helpful. Or you can just pass in an array of functions as an argument. More information on the use case would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some really cool new feature called rest parameters. Here is an example.

```
function callMultiple(...fn) {
 fn.forEach(fn => fn());
}

function FnOne() {
 console.log('function one called');
}

function FnTwo() {
 console.log('function two called');
}

callMultiple(FnOne, FnTwo);
```

Now callMultiple can take any number of functions.
[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Answer (score 2):

```
function doFn(){    
   for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) arguments[i]();
}
```

One line ES6:

```
  var doFn = (...args) => args.forEach(fn => fn());
```

PD: ´do´ is a reserved word, you should use diffetent variable name.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to your `do()` function is this:

```
function do(args) {    
    for (var i = 1; i <= args.length; i += 1) {
        args[i]();
    }
}
```

This would fix your problem. However, you should know that `do` is a JavaScript keyword, so you should avoid using it as a variable or function of your own.

EDIT: You must include anything you're passing to your function, so you need to add the `args` parameter.